# C# System.Type doesn't contains GetProperties()

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

I created an Universal App which uses SQLite.
Then I created a method which uses `GetType().GetProperties()`
My problem is that in a previous version of my app(not universal), I used this method and it worked perfectly, now i can't use him couse the `Type` Class doesn't contains it.

I checked the System.Type class and this was the header of the working one:

```
#region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v2.0.5.0
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\mscorlib.dll
#endregion

using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;
```

And this is the header of the Universal App's one:

```
    #region Assembly System.Runtime.dll, v4.0.10.0
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\System.Runtime.dll
#endregion

using System.Security;
```

The second doesn't contain `GetMethod`, or `GetProperties`, or a lot of other methods.

The only difference is that the universal app had 8.1 as destination and Windows phone app has 8.0.
Any ideas on how to use `Type.GetProperties()` method?

Answer (score 2):

use `GetType().GetRuntimeProperties()` instead of `GetType().GetProperties()` for universal Apps.

Comment: thanks a lot, this method and the post linked by @DavidG solved my problem